# what is the easiest way to extend an existing data structure to include semaphore or similar methods in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, mutex, semaphore

I have an existing c++ code.

```
    boost::asio::ip::address m_sender_IP_address;




void Udp_comm::start_receive()
{
    //receive UDP message
    m_sock_r.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer), 
        m_sender_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&Udp_comm::handle_receive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)); 
}

void Udp_comm::handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, const std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::string recvd_message(m_recv_buffer.begin(), m_recv_buffer.begin() + bytes_transferred);
    m_sender_IP_address = m_sender_endpoint.address();//////////wait here
        //continue to listening to future messages
    start_receive();
    process_message(m_sender_IP_addres.to_string(), recvd_message);
}
```

How to protect m_sender_IP_address from getting overwritten by next UDP message received? I want lock access to that variable from 2nd line in `handle_receive` method to the 1st line in `process_message` method

can I also acheive something similar without using locks?

Comment: [This](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/426698/scope-guarded-lockable-objects-in-c11) might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semaphore is not necessary here. You can use a `strand` to ensure an asynchronous handler is invoked concurrently once at most. To do this, create a wrapped handler for the `async_receieve_from()` callback

```
void Udp_comm::start_receive()
{
    //receive UDP message
    m_sock_r.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer), 
        m_sender_endpoint,
        m_strand.wrap(
                boost::bind(
                    &Udp_comm::handle_receive,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                )
            )
        );  
}
```

Here `m_strand` is a member of `Udp_comm`. Doing this will guarantee only one thread can mutate `m_sender_IP_address`.